# how to extract n digit numbers in a text including special characters

Tags: python-3.x

i have a text full of regular expression and I want to extract the numbers that have 4 digits,

```
mytext ="""A text including special characters like 1000+(100)=1100 """
numbers = []
seperators=[
'(', ')',  '[',  ']',  '{',  '}',   ';',   ':',  '=', '+',   '-',  '/', '*', '&', '%', '$',  '@', '#',   '^',   '*',  '~',  '`', '"',  '>',   '|',   '\\', '?',  '.',  '<',  "'"]
```

how to use split function to extract numbers?

```
for word in mytext2.split(seperators):
    
   if word.isdigit():
      numbers.append(int(word))
    
#print(numbers)

for mynumbers in numbers:
    if mynumbers >999 and 10000>mynumbers: #for 4 digits
        print(mynumbers)


#this should print all the 4 digit numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "A text including special characters like 1000+(100)=1100 "

import re

numbers = [int(number) for number in re.findall(r'\b\d{4}\b', text)]
print(numbers)
# Outputs [1000, 1001]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mytext ="""Alain Fabien Maurice Marcel Delon (French: [al d l ] ɛ̃ ə ɔ̃; born 8 November 1935) is a French actor and businessman. He is known as
one of Europe's most prominent actors and screen sex symbols from the 1960s and 1970s. He achieved critical acclaim for roles in
films such as Rocco and His Brothers (1960), Plein Soleil (1960), L'Eclisse (1962), The Leopard (1963), The Yellow Rolls-
Royce (1965), Lost Command (1966), and Le Samouraï (1967). Over the course of his career Delon worked with many wellknown directors, including Luchino Visconti, Jean-Luc Godard, Jean-Pierre Melville, Michelangelo Antonioni, and Louis Malle. He
acquired Swiss citizenship in 1999"""



numbers = []
seperators=['#','(',')','$','%','^','&','*','+']
mytext2=mytext
mytext2=mytext2.replace('(',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace(')',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('[',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace(']',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('{',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('}',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace(';',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace(':',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('=',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('+',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('-',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('/',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('*',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('&',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('%',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('$',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('@',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('#',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('^',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('*',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('~',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('`',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('"',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('>',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('|',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('\\',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('?',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('.',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace('<',' ' )
mytext2=mytext2.replace("'",' ' )
#print(mytext2)
for word in mytext2.split():
    
   if word.isdigit():
      numbers.append(int(word))
    
#print(numbers)

for mynumbers in numbers:
    if mynumbers >999 and 10000>mynumbers:
        print(mynumbers)
```

this code prints all the n digit numbers in the text, if your text more special characters you should add  them in the first part to be replaced.